# Using awk / sed to find and replace key value pair from file to other

Tags: awk, sed

I have a key value file, named `key.txt`, with a `:` separator.
This is how values are displayed:

```
server_name:server1
username:someuser
keyname:123key
```

My second file is a script file, which has these keys all over the file. It shows up in following format anywhere in file doesn't matter which line or column:

```
what is the servername '%%server_name%%'
Enter your username '%%username%%' 
What is the ssh key value '%%keyname%%'
```

What I want to do is when I run the command it will find the key `server_name` in my second file and replace the key `%%server_name%%` with value from file one which is `server1`, but make sure it has quotes before and after.

So my new file will look like this:

```
what is the servername 'server1' 
Enter your username 'someuser' 
What is the ssh key value '123key'
```

I looked on forum found this code but unable to make it work.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {url[$1]=$2; next} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in url) $i=url[$i]; print}' key.txt file2.txt

+ xxd keys.txt
0000000: 7371 6c5f 7365 7276 6572 5f6e 616d 653a  sql_server_name:
0000010: 7465 7374 5f73 6571 7365 7276 6572 5f31  test_seqserver_1
0000020: 3233 340d 0a0d 0a73 716c 5f6c 6f67 696e  234....sql_login
0000030: 5f6e 616d 653a 7465 7374 5f6c 6f67 696e  _name:test_login
0000040: 5f6e 616d 650d 0a0d 0a70 6173 7377 6f72  _name....passwor
0000050: 643a 7465 7374 5f70 6173 7377 6f72 6420  d:test_password 
0000060: 0d0a 0d0a 5349 443a 3132 3334 3536 200d  ....SID:123456 .
0000070: 0a0d 0a64 6566 6175 6c74 5f64 6174 6162  ...default_datab
0000080: 6173 653a 7465 6d70 6462 0d0a 0d0a 6465  ase:tempdb....de
0000090: 6661 756c 745f 6c61 6e67 7561 6765 3a75  fault_language:u
00000a0: 735f 656e 676c 6973 680d 0a0d 0a63 6865  s_english....che
00000b0: 636b 5f65 7870 6972 6174 696f 6e3a 4f46  ck_expiration:OF
00000c0: 460d 0a0d 0a63 6865 636b 5f70 6f6c 6963  F....check_polic
00000d0: 793a 4f46 460d 0a0d 0a64 656c 6976 6572  y:OFF....deliver
00000e0: 7974 7970 653a 7363 6865 6475 6c65 640d  ytype:scheduled.
00000f0: 0a0d 0a73 6368 6564 756c 6564 5f64 656c  ...scheduled_del
0000100: 6976 6572 7964 6174 653a 3035 2d33 302d  iverydate:05-30-
0000110: 3230 3939 0d0a 0d0a 7363 6865 6475 6c65  2099....schedule
0000120: 645f 6465 6c69 7665 7279 5f32 3468 725f  d_delivery_24hr_
0000130: 6365 6e74 7261 6c5f 7469 6d65 3a31 3135  central_time:115
0000140: 3920 0d0a 0d0a 0d0a 0d0a 0d0a 0d0a 0d0a  9 ..............
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sed to turn `key.txt` into a series of sed substitutions, then run these on your input file:

```
$ sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d;s|^|s/%%|;s|:|%%/|;s|$|/|' key.txt | sed -f - infile
what is the servername 'server1'
Enter your username 'someuser'
What is the ssh key value '123key'
```

The first sed command has this output:

```
s/%%server_name%%/server1/
s/%%username%%/someuser/
s/%%keyname%%/123key/
```

Then we run these commands with `sed -f -`, where `-f` says "read commands from a file", and the special file `-` is standard input.

---

A closer look at what the first command does:

```
sed '
/^[[:blank:]]*$/d  # Delete blank lines in key file
s|^|s/%%|          # Insert "s/%%" at the start of the line
s|:|%%/|           # Replace ":" with "%%/"
s|$|/|             # Insert "/" at the end of the line
' key.txt
```

I'm using `|` as delimiter instead of the more common `/` so I don't have to escape my slashes: `s/$/\//` would work, too.