# Jenkins pipeline failing for sed command

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sed

I'm running a sed command in pipeline but it is failing with an error

```
sed: file - line 2: unterminated `s' command
```

here is my code for sed in pipeline:

```
sh '''sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d;s|^|s/%%|;s|:|%%/|;s|$|/|' key.txt | sed -f - file1.txt > file2.txt'''
```

I if I will run only first sed command, Jenkins gives very strange output, here it is from Jenkins logs its adding extra lines with characters:

```
+ sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d;s|^|s@%%|;s|:|%%@|;s|$|@|' keys.txt
s@%%sql_server_name%%@test_seqserver_1234
@
s@%%
@
s@%%sql_login_name%%@test_login_name
@
s@%%
@
s@%%password%%@test_password 
@
s@%%
@
```

If run following command this is what Jenkins output looks like

```
sh '''sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d;/:/!d;s|^|s/%%|;s|:|%%/|;s|$|/|' 
keys.txt'''
```

Jenkins output:

```
+ sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d;/:/!d;s|^|s/%%|;s|:|%%/|;s|$|/|' keys.txt
s/%%sql_server_name%%/test_seqserver_1234
/
s/%%sql_login_name%%/test_login_name
/
s/%%password%%/test_password 
/
s/%%SID%%/123456 
/
```

I ran the new command:

```
sh '''sed -e '/:/!d;s|^\\([^:]*\\):\\(.*\\)$|s/%%\\1%%/\\2/|' -e 'N;s|\\n/|/|' keys.txt'''
```

Here is the output:

```
Running shell script
+ sed -e '/:/!d;s|^\([^:]*\):\(.*\)$|s/%%\1%%/\2/|' -e 'N;s|\n/|/|' 
keys.txt
s/%%sql_server_name%%/test_seqserver_1234
/

s/%%sql_login_name%%/test_login_name
/

s/%%password%%/test_password 
/

s/%%SID%%/123456
```

Here is xxd output for text file:

```
Running shell script
+ xxd keys.txt
0000000: 7371 6c5f 7365 7276 6572 5f6e 616d 653a  sql_server_name:
0000010: 7465 7374 5f73 6571 7365 7276 6572 5f31  test_seqserver_1
0000020: 3233 340d 0a0d 0a73 716c 5f6c 6f67 696e  234....sql_login
0000030: 5f6e 616d 653a 7465 7374 5f6c 6f67 696e  _name:test_login
0000040: 5f6e 616d 650d 0a0d 0a70 6173 7377 6f72  _name....passwor
0000050: 643a 7465 7374 5f70 6173 7377 6f72 6420  d:test_password 
0000060: 0d0a 0d0a 5349 443a 3132 3334 3536 200d  ....SID:123456 .
0000070: 0a0d 0a64 6566 6175 6c74 5f64 6174 6162  ...default_datab
0000080: 6173 653a 7465 6d70 6462 0d0a 0d0a 6465  ase:tempdb....de
0000090: 6661 756c 745f 6c61 6e67 7561 6765 3a75  fault_language:u
00000a0: 735f 656e 676c 6973 680d 0a0d 0a63 6865  s_english....che
00000b0: 636b 5f65 7870 6972 6174 696f 6e3a 4f46  ck_expiration:OF
00000c0: 460d 0a0d 0a63 6865 636b 5f70 6f6c 6963  F....check_polic
00000d0: 793a 4f46 460d 0a0d 0a64 656c 6976 6572  y:OFF....deliver
00000e0: 7974 7970 653a 7363 6865 6475 6c65 640d  ytype:scheduled.
00000f0: 0a0d 0a73 6368 6564 756c 6564 5f64 656c  ...scheduled_del
0000100: 6976 6572 7964 6174 653a 3035 2d33 302d  iverydate:05-30-
0000110: 3230 3939 0d0a 0d0a 7363 6865 6475 6c65  2099....schedule
0000120: 645f 6465 6c69 7665 7279 5f32 3468 725f  d_delivery_24hr_
0000130: 6365 6e74 7261 6c5f 7469 6d65 3a31 3135  central_time:115
0000140: 3920 0d0a 0d0a 0d0a 0d0a 0d0a 0d0a 0d0a  9 ..............
```

Comment: This error depends on contents of key.txt. What is your key.txt?

Comment: See also the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50262468/3266847) for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your key.txt file has incorrect value. Judging from the first sed command:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d; s|^|s/%%|; s|:|%%/|; s|$|/|' key.txt
```

it expects each line to contain a semicolon. Then it forms sed code for the second sed command:

```
sed -f - file1.txt > file2.txt
```

If your key.txt contains non-empty lines without a semicolon, you will get the error `unterminated 's' command`.

Ensure that key.txt is correct, or at least add `/:/!d;` into your pipeline. Like this:

```
sh '''sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d;/:/!d;s|^|s/%%|;s|:|%%/|;s|$|/|' key.txt | sed -f - file1.txt > file2.txt'''
```

For example, correct key.txt contents:

```
username:server1
```

Incorrect key.txt:

```
username server2
```

There is no semicolon in this line, so it will cause error.

---

You might try to replace your first sed command with a simpler one:

```
sed '/:/!d;s|^\([^:]*\):\(.*\)$|s/%%\1%%/\2/|' key.txt
```

or better:

```
sed -e '/:/!d;s|^\([^:]*\):\(.*\)$|s/%%\1%%/\2/|' -e 'N;s|\n/|/|' key.txt
```

If that doesn't help, run `xxd key.txt` or `hexdump -C key.txt` and post the output.

---

After you added hex contents of your key.txt file, I finally could replicate the issue on my machine. The problem could be solved by this command:

```
sed -e '/:/!d;s|^\([^:]*\):\(.*\)\r|s/%%\1%%/\2/|' key.txt
```

So the trick is to use `\r` instead of `$` in the first sed command. If it still doesn't work for you (it might, if you use MacOS), you can just [remove carriage return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) from the key.txt file with a tool of your choice (like `dos2unix`) and then your original code should work.

Comment: my key.txt file is a key value file, where : is the separator. When I run my command in Jenkins its adding extra 3 lines. I'm going to edit my question and show you the output from first sed command, very strange output by jenkins

Comment: if I run only first sed statement, I get a extra line with a / only. I'm pasting output in my question with your command.

Comment: @dino110, looks like your are dealing with some unusual sed implementation, which interprets `s|$|/|` differently from GNU sed.

Comment: getting an errro ....org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 17: unexpected char: '\' @ line 17, column 29.
           sh '''sed '/:/!d;s|^\([^:]*\):\(.*\)$|s/%%\1%%/\2/|' key.txt'''

Comment: Update your answer with my output

Comment: @dino110, you are not supposed to post your comments in my answer. I updated the answer with another solution and debugging suggestion.

Comment: My apologies, I have updated my question with new output and debug output.

Comment: @dino110, that helped. Updated my answer.